# Error while passing a URL from Database to webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium with Python to **scrape** some data .The code is working fine for a single URL(If we hardcode the URL), In our case we have many URL's and i have planned to pass the URL to the webdriver from database.

But when i did that it is giving exceptions, Below is the code and exceptions.Can anyone let me know what i'm doing wrong?

i'm getting exception on this line **browser.get(passed_url)**
but if i pass it as string like below it is working   browser.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=vitamin+b12')

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import psycopg2
import os
import glob
import datetime


option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" — incognito")
#browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver/', chrome_options=option)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/users/user_123/downloads/chrome_driver/chromedriver', chrome_options=option)

try:
#Database connection string
 DSN = "dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='postgres' port='5432'"
 #DWH table to which data is ported
 TABLE_NAME = 'staging.search_url'
 #Connecting DB..
 conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
 print("Database connected...")
 conn.set_client_encoding('latin-1')
 cur = conn.cursor()
 cur.execute("SET datestyle='German'")
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
 print('database connection failed')
 quit()



search_url_fetch="""select url_to_be_searched from staging.search_url"""
psql_cursor = conn.cursor()
psql_cursor.execute(search_url_fetch)
serach_url_list = psql_cursor.fetchall()
print('Fetched DB values')
for row in serach_url_list:
    passed_url=''
    passed_url=str(row)
    passed_url=passed_url.replace(',)','')
    passed_url=passed_url.replace('(','')
    print(passed_url)
    print("\n")
    
    browser.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=vitamin+b12')
    #browser.get(passed_url)
    full_titles_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mnr-c pla-unit']")
    # use list comprehension to get the actual repo titles and not the selenium objects.
    full_text_title = [x.text for x in full_titles_element]
    # print out all the titles.
    print('Whole names that appear in site:')
    print(full_text_title, '\n')


    product_name_list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='pymv4e']")
    # use list comprehension to get the actual repo titles and not the selenium objects.
    #upd_product_name_list=list(filter(None, product_name_list))

    upd_product_name_list=list(filter(None, product_name_list))
    product_name = [x.text for x in product_name_list]
    print('Product names:')
    print(product_name, '\n')
    filtered = [x for x in product_name if len(x.strip()) > 0]
    print(filtered)
    element_length=(len(filtered))
    print(element_length)
    print("\n")

    positions=[]
    for x in range(1, element_length+1):
        positions.append(x)
    print(positions)    
    print("\n")

    company_name_list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='LbUacb']")
    # use list comprehension to get the actual repo titles and not the selenium objects.
    company = [x.text for x in company_name_list]
    # print out all the titles.
    print('Company Name:')
    print(company, '\n')

    urls=[]
    find_href = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='plantl pla-unit-single-clickable-target clickable-card']")
    for my_href in find_href:
        url_list=my_href.get_attribute("href")
        urls.append(url_list)
        #print(my_href.get_attribute("href"))
    print(urls)
    print("\n")
    result = zip(positions,filtered, urls, company)

    print(tuple(result))
```

**Exceptions:**

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Users/user_123/Documents/PLA/selenium_chrome_with_beautiful_soup.py", line 16
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/users/user_123/downloads/chrome_driver/chromedriver', chrome_options=option)
DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options

Database connected...
Fetched DB values
'https://www.google.com/search?q=vitamin+b12'


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user_123/Documents/PLA/selenium_chrome_with_beautiful_soup.py", line 49, in <module>
    browser.get(passed_url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the `'` quote and the beginning and end of the string. See below I trimmed them off the string and assigned a new variable `new_url`.

Answer :

```
new_url = passed_url[1:len(passed_url)-1]
browser.get(new_url)
```

---

Example:

```
a = "'https://www.google.com/search?q=vitamin+b12'"
b = a[1:len(a)-1]
print(a)
print(b)
```

Your edited code below:

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import psycopg2
import os
import glob
import datetime

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" — incognito")
#browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver/', chrome_options=option)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/users/user_123/downloads/chrome_driver/chromedriver', chrome_options=option)
try:
#Database connection string
 DSN = "dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='postgres' port='5432'"
 #DWH table to which data is ported
 TABLE_NAME = 'staging.search_url'
 #Connecting DB..
 conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
 print("Database connected...")
 conn.set_client_encoding('latin-1')
 cur = conn.cursor()
 cur.execute("SET datestyle='German'")
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
 print('database connection failed')
 quit()



search_url_fetch="""select url_to_be_searched from staging.search_url"""
psql_cursor = conn.cursor()
psql_cursor.execute(search_url_fetch)
serach_url_list = psql_cursor.fetchall()
print('Fetched DB values')
for row in serach_url_list:
    passed_url=''
    passed_url=str(row)
    passed_url=passed_url.replace(',)','')
    passed_url=passed_url.replace('(','')
    new_url = passed_url[1:len(passed_url)-1]
    print(passed_url)
    print("\n")

    #browser.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=vitamin+b12')
    browser.get(new_url)
    full_titles_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mnr-c pla-unit']")
    # use list comprehension to get the actual repo titles and not the selenium objects.
    full_text_title = [x.text for x in full_titles_element]
    # print out all the titles.
    print('Whole names that appear in site:')
    print(full_text_title, '\n')


    product_name_list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='pymv4e']")
    # use list comprehension to get the actual repo titles and not the selenium objects.
    #upd_product_name_list=list(filter(None, product_name_list))

    upd_product_name_list=list(filter(None, product_name_list))
    product_name = [x.text for x in product_name_list]
    print('Product names:')
    print(product_name, '\n')
    filtered = [x for x in product_name if len(x.strip()) > 0]
    print(filtered)
    element_length=(len(filtered))
    print(element_length)
    print("\n")

    positions=[]
    for x in range(1, element_length+1):
        positions.append(x)
    print(positions)    
    print("\n")

    company_name_list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='LbUacb']")
    # use list comprehension to get the actual repo titles and not the selenium objects.
    company = [x.text for x in company_name_list]
    # print out all the titles.
    print('Company Name:')
    print(company, '\n')

    urls=[]
    find_href = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='plantl pla-unit-single-clickable-target clickable-card']")
    for my_href in find_href:
        url_list=my_href.get_attribute("href")
        urls.append(url_list)
        #print(my_href.get_attribute("href"))
    print(urls)
    print("\n")
    result = zip(positions,filtered, urls, company)

    print(tuple(result))
```

Comment: Got this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user_123/Documents/hgh.py", line 45, in <module>
    new_url = passed_url[passed_url[1:len(passed_url)-1]]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Could you just include the code needed to make the fix in this answer (rather than pasting the entire code sample from the OP's question)? It will help clarify where exactly the issue is

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem, that has been made clear in your question -- I am asking the poster of this answer to include a more concise code sample in their fix -- looking through this answer, it is hard to tell where the fix has been made due to how long the code sample is.

Comment: @Sandeep I messed that all the way up, sorry about that, see the edited answer.